# my slidershow doesn't work on host

Tags: jquery, html, css, slideshow

i uploaded my website on my host. the only problem that i have is my slidershow. it is good in local host but when i put it on the host it doesn't work. i troubleshooted it on the 
view page source to find the broken link and find no broken link. 
[this](http://2day.hisend.ir/) is my website and i wrap my slidershow with green 1px border.

```
 <script src="http://2day.hisend.ir/wp-content/themes/2day/js/vendor/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://2day.hisend.ir/wp-content/themes/2day/js/thumbnail-slider.js"></script>
        <section id="slidershow">
                    <div class="slider_top"><span>اخبار</span></div>
                    <hr class="slider_line" />
                     <div class="div2">
        <div id="mcts1">
            <div class="each">


                <div class="content">
                              <h2><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%af%d8%a7%d9%86%d9%84%d9%88%d8%af-%d9%85%d9%88%d8%b2%db%8c%da%a9-%d8%a7%d8%a8%d8%b1%d8%a7%d9%87%db%8c%d9%85-%d9%be%d8%a7%d8%b1%d8%b3/">دانلود موزیک ابراهیم پارس</a></h2>
                    <p><p>دانلود موزیک ابراهیم پاس موزیک 24</p>
a ss ka samd.,m sa,dm sa.,md .,samd. ,sma.,  a.sm,sm .s . ..as,s, ,,s,s,,sdms,md,sd, m m ms,dms,dm mm m dsjdl ksa  l;as;ld ksa;ld k;slak ;la l lsak ;lsak ;lk ;lsak;l ks l
                    salds akl; ka;ls k;slk ;slk ;slkd;lk ;ldsak ldk ;sk;s lksd;ld ks;ldk s;lk s
                    s adklsk s k;sa ksa sla ksa ;lsakd ;ls</p>
                    <hr/>

                    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%b3%db%8c%d9%86%d9%85%d8%a7-%d9%86%d8%a8%d8%a7%d8%b4%d8%af-%d8%af%d9%86%db%8c%d8%a7-%d9%86%db%8c%d8%b3%d8%aa/">سینما نباشد دنیا نیست</a></li>

<li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%a8%d8%a7%d8%a8-%d8%a7%d8%b3%d9%81%d9%86%d8%ac%db%8c/">باب اسفنجی</a></li>

<li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d9%81%d9%88%d8%aa%d8%a8%d8%a7%d9%84%db%8c%d8%b3%d8%aa-%d9%87%d8%a7/">فوتبالیست ها</a></li>


                        </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="each">


                <div class="content">
                              <h2><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d9%85%d8%a7-%d8%ae%d9%88%d8%a7%d8%b3%d8%aa%d8%a7%d8%b1-%d8%b5%d9%84%d8%ad-%d9%87%d8%b3%d8%aa%db%8c%d9%85/">ما خواستار صلح هستیم</a></h2>
                    <p><p>سشمن شمسکمی کسشم شسکم شکمس شس کمشسم کسشم شسکی مسکگیمش س یم شسکگیمشس کگمیسشک گمسش ک مکشسم کسشم شس گشکمسیک گمسشگی</p>
</p>
                    <hr/>

                    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%aa%d8%a7-%d8%ae%d9%88%d9%86-%d8%af%d8%b1-%d8%b1%da%af-%d9%85%d8%a7%d8%b3%d8%aa/">تا خون در رگ ماست</a></li>


                        </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
                       <div class="each">


                <div class="content">
                              <h2><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d9%85%d8%a7-%d8%ae%d9%88%d8%a7%d8%b3%d8%aa%d8%a7%d8%b1-%d8%b5%d9%84%d8%ad-%d9%87%d8%b3%d8%aa%db%8c%d9%85/">ما خواستار صلح هستیم</a></h2>
                    <p><p>سشمن شمسکمی کسشم شسکم شکمس شس کمشسم کسشم شسکی مسکگیمش س یم شسکگیمشس کگمیسشک گمسش ک مکشسم کسشم شس گشکمسیک گمسشگی</p>
</p>
                    <hr/>

                    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%aa%d8%a7-%d8%ae%d9%88%d9%86-%d8%af%d8%b1-%d8%b1%da%af-%d9%85%d8%a7%d8%b3%d8%aa/">تا خون در رگ ماست</a></li>


                        </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
                      <div class="each">


                <div class="content">
                              <h2><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d9%85%d8%a7-%d8%ae%d9%88%d8%a7%d8%b3%d8%aa%d8%a7%d8%b1-%d8%b5%d9%84%d8%ad-%d9%87%d8%b3%d8%aa%db%8c%d9%85/">ما خواستار صلح هستیم</a></h2>
                    <p><p>سشمن شمسکمی کسشم شسکم شکمس شس کمشسم کسشم شسکی مسکگیمش س یم شسکگیمشس کگمیسشک گمسش ک مکشسم کسشم شس گشکمسیک گمسشگی</p>
</p>
                    <hr/>

                    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%aa%d8%a7-%d8%ae%d9%88%d9%86-%d8%af%d8%b1-%d8%b1%da%af-%d9%85%d8%a7%d8%b3%d8%aa/">تا خون در رگ ماست</a></li>


                        </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
                                 <div class="each">


                <div class="content">
                              <h2><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d9%85%d8%a7-%d8%ae%d9%88%d8%a7%d8%b3%d8%aa%d8%a7%d8%b1-%d8%b5%d9%84%d8%ad-%d9%87%d8%b3%d8%aa%db%8c%d9%85/">ما خواستار صلح هستیم</a></h2>
                    <p><p>سشمن شمسکمی کسشم شسکم شکمس شس کمشسم کسشم شسکی مسکگیمش س یم شسکگیمشس کگمیسشک گمسش ک مکشسم کسشم شس گشکمسیک گمسشگی</p>
</p>
                    <hr/>

                    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%aa%d8%a7-%d8%ae%d9%88%d9%86-%d8%af%d8%b1-%d8%b1%da%af-%d9%85%d8%a7%d8%b3%d8%aa/">تا خون در رگ ماست</a></li>


                        </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>  
    </div>              </section>
```

Comment: Check your console and fix 404 errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some files missing:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://2day.hisend.ir/wp-content/themes/2day/cufon-1.10.min.js"
cufon-1.10.min.js
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://2day.hisend.ir/wp-content/themes/2day/bifon-1.1b.min.js"
bifon-1.1b.min.js
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://2day.hisend.ir/wp-content/themes/2day/myfont.js"
myfont.js
ReferenceError: Cufon is not defined

ReferenceError: simpleSlide is not defined
```

Comment: i have problem with my slidershow not with font and also these files are not effect my website because there is no need of theme i just delete theme

Comment: javascript stops on reference error. So you have to fix cufon at first.
Then there is a missing SimpleSlide. If you fix cufon, I#am confident it works.

Comment: yes there were missing so i just remove theme because i don't use them in my template.

Comment: if u visit [my website link](http://2day.hisend.ir/) again. you'll find that it isn't solved

Comment: please bin in first jquery than the slider-plug-in, just to be sure.
Than your main.js is empty. Where is your code?

Comment: Code found. please place this line "var thumbnailSlider = new ThumbnailSlider(mct1_Options);" to your main.js and wrap it with a document ready

Comment: this code does not need a starter as you can see i just add above line to my website but the problem is still resist. i have download this plugin from [this site](http://www.menucool.com/slider/content-slider)

Comment: If the content is not ready. the slider-plug-in can not find the id="mcts1"

Comment: I' have seen your new bug:
This silder is not started by giving an id, how you did it. You have to pass all options. Simple add this line after doc.ready:
var thumbnailSlider = new ThumbnailSlider(mct1_Options);

Comment: the  var thumbnailSlider = new ThumbnailSlider(mct1_Options);  command have been added before if you'll look at the file name thumbnail-slider.js on my website you will find that this file added before?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48788/discussion-between-hussein-and-hamburger)